# How to program Button 4 and Button 5 to act as Button 1 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, mouse, button

I have recently bought a new gaming mouse for my computer, and then a gaming keyboard, and they both have matching Blue lights. They are pretty good, but I have a question about my mouse. It has two extra buttons on the side, and I soon figured out that they are referred to as "Button 4" and "Button 5" in some Windows programs (I'm dual booting Windows and Ubuntu). I want a simple way to make Button 4 and Button 5 act as the Left Click, or "Button 1." Can someone help?

Thanks,

Aidan Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the package `xautomation`, we need the command `xte`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xautomation
   ```
2. Edit your `xbindkeys` configuration, e.g.:

   ```
   nano ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

   and add the following lines

   ```
   "xte 'mouseclick 1'"
        b:4

   "xte 'mouseclick 1'"
        b:5
   ```

   - from `man xte`

     ```
     mouseclick i
         Click mouse button i
     ```
3. Kill all `kbindkeys` processes

   ```
   killall xbindkeys
   ```
4. Restart `xbindkeys` with your configuration, eg:

   ```
   xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

Comment: This isn't working. Also, when I opened the .xbindkeysrc file, it was blank. Is it supposed to be blank?

Comment: Yes, normally it's empty or non-existent

Comment: And sorry, there was an error in my answer, copy and paste the lines with `xte …` again. There was a missing single quote.